# Inner and outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Have a question regarding an answer to a question:

[Inner and outer measures equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044580/inner-and-outer-measures-equality)

How would one go about proving Step 1? The only way I can find involves taking an infinite Union and then an infinite intersection, which does not guarantee that our set $\in \S(R)$ as this is a ring which is not necessarily closed under countable unions

Comment: Note that $S(R)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $R$; it is clearly stable under countable intersections/unions.

Comment: @saz Thanks, of course that is true. I have been trying to establish the result in the question for the minimal ring generated by subsets of X. I have gotten it down to proving a statement that is the second most recent question I've asked; is this statement true and how should I go about proving it. Been fiddling with it for 2/3 hours and gotten nowhere